# Date and time manipulation in R

Tags: r, date, time, format, lubridate

I am trying to prep these dates and times for analysis. The time is tricky because its in military time from Lithuania (which is 10 hours ahead of the US). my question is how to convert the time to correct US time? Also, how to split the column into two columns separating the date and time?

Here is my example data:

```
a <- c("10/4/2016 21:11","10/11/2016 19:53" ,"9/16/2016 0:39",
   "8/17/2016 21:46","11/16/2016 9:37","11/29/2016 16:14",
   "10/7/2016 20:14","9/16/2016 0:27","9/27/2016 23:10",
   "2/24/2015 20:37","11/8/2016 21:05","5/25/2016 1:30",
   "8/5/2016 0:41","8/22/2016 23:02","5/25/2016 0:43",
   "9/28/2016 22:17","9/14/2016 22:58","8/25/2016 18:10","10/10/2016 16:55" ,"10/7/2016 0:11")

df <- data.frame(Date=a, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want:

```
>df
     Date       Time
1  2016-10-04  9:11 PM
2  2016-10-11  6:53 PM
3  2016-09-16  1:39 AM
4  2016-08-17  9:46 PM
```

Comment: Usually the desire is to have a unified datetime but I guess this request is not new. You should do more searching before further questioning. The times are stored as UCT times at the input stage and output allows "shifting" of tz with the tx and usetz parameters to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to learn about formatting date-time values is `?strptime`. Most of htat knowledge applies to the as.Date and format.Date and format.POSIXt functions. For display of the times, you need to do the input correctly, then do the output:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"),
                 Time=format( as.POSIXct( df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 
                              format="%I:%M %p") )
> df2
         Date     Time
1  2016-10-04 09:11 PM
2  2016-10-11 07:53 PM
3  2016-09-16 12:39 AM
4  2016-08-17 09:46 PM
5  2016-11-16 09:37 AM
snipped output
```

Each of the `"%_"` items is described on a separate entry of the `?strptime` help page. You can add literals like "?", ":", and spaces where needed to get the pattern matching process to occur correctly. The `lubridate`-package has some additional capability if your formatting were more irregular. There is also the `chron`-package that allows separation of times and dates, but it doesn't seem to be used as much these days.

This shows how to read in Lithuanian military time and output as New_York time:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), 
                  Time=format( as.POSIXct( df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", 
                                           usetz=TRUE, tz="Etc/GMT-2"), # input
                              "%I:%M %p", tz="EST5EDT") ) # output
```

Could also use `tz="Europe/Vilnius"` at the input stage. The fixed offset would not accomodate DST changes, while the "Europe/Vilnius" choice would (depending on what your system configuration of the Olson database supports.)

Comment: In addition, for dealing with the timezone difference, for instance the `with_tz()` function can be used from the `lubridate` package (after defining the Lithuanian timezone correctly during parsing). A list of valid timezones can be found by executing `OlsonNames()`

Comment: Do you know how to take into account the 10 hour time difference?

Comment: Read it as Lithuanian time, perhaps with something like tz="Etc/GMT-3" and use `format(..)` for output as described in my comments to your question. (That info should have been accessible with a bit of searching and mpjdem gave you another useful resource: `lubridate::with_tz`.)